# Array of structs conversion c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct

I have a legacy c++ dll that uses the following structs in the calling code

```
struct deal
{
    int trump;
    int first;
    int currentTrickSuit[3];
    int currentTrickRank[3];
    unsigned int remainCards[DDS_HANDS][DDS_SUITS];
};

struct boards
{
    int noOfBoards;
    struct deal deals[MAXNOOFBOARDS];
    int target[MAXNOOFBOARDS];
    int solutions[MAXNOOFBOARDS];
    int mode[MAXNOOFBOARDS];
};
```

The first of these might be converted as

```
 struct deal
{
    int trump;
    int first;
    fixed int currentTrickSuit[3];
    fixed int currentTrickRank[3];
    fixed ushort remainCards[DDS_HANDS][DDS_SUITS];
};
```

But how best to handle

```
struct deal deals[MAXNOOFBOARDS];
```

(MAXNOOFBOARDS is typically #defined as 200 ) ?

Comment: Your C# example is wrong because the `int[]` arrays will be allocated elsewhere on the managed heap and referred to by reference rather than allocated in-place. Use the `fixed` keyword. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers

Comment: No different in c# than c++.  for an integer which is 4 bytes you are allocating 4 * 200 bytes.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I'd read that.  Will change the question as you say.

Comment: @jdweng The dll is very compute intensive and highly optimized.  Memory won't usually be a limitation so keeping the structs as similar as possible would be the main priority.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're scenario here? it isn't *necessarily* the case that you need `deals[MAXNOOFBOARDS];` to be allocated via `fixed` - most likely an array would be fine, and indeed, it is **actively harmful** to have structs that are immense, unless you're *really* careful about how you access them (to avoid copy semantics, which would be disastrous here)

Comment: @ Marc Gravell does my answer to jdweng help?  Keeping the code as similar as possible would be my main concern.

Comment: You are not asking this question the Smart Way.  Most any popular C library has an existing .NET wrapper, this one is [no exception](https://github.com/anorsich/dds.net).  If you don't want to use it then at least look at how the author "handled" it.

Comment: @Hans Passant One needs to be smart to ask in the Smart Way.  That's very useful - thanks.